# Ошибка 11501 при установке Symantec Management Server Configuration Wizard: Unable to Connect the database

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте. Вот такая ошибка выскакивает при установке Management Server Configuration от Symantec (на втором изображении). Из - за неё установка дальше невозможна. Ссылка, предлагаемая этой ошибкой (Please Click here for more information) предлагает два решения, но сам я не могу понять, что нужно сделать. Прошу умных людей объяснить на пальцах. Возможно, это важно: SQL 2014 года, скачан с официального сайта Microsoft. Файл SQLEXPR32_x86_RUS.

Копирую текст предлагаемого решения:

> There are two problems that can cause this error message to appear.
>   Network connectivity between the Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager
>   and the Microsoft SQL Server is unavailable Ensure that the Symantec
>   Endpoint Protection Manager can communicate with the SQL server.
>   Ensure that the SQL server's IP address is entered correctly in the
>   Server Configuration Wizard on the Manager. Use the ping command to
>   determine whether network traffic can flow between the Manager and the
>   SQL server. The TCP/IP protocol is disabled in Microsoft SQL Server
>   itself In this case, enable the TCP/IP protocol in Microsoft SQL
>   Server. To enable TCP/IP, follow the instructions for your version of
>   Microsoft SQL Server:
>       Microsoft SQL Server 2000:
>       In SQL Server Network Utility, add TCP/IP to the Enabled protocols list.
>       Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or 2008:
>       In SQL Server Configuration Manager, go to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER, and enable TCP/IP protocol.
>   Once you enable the TCP/IP protocol, restart the SQL Server service.

Конкретнее - я понял, что на в конфигурации SQL сервера нужно включить протокол TCP/IP. Это я сделал. Но ошибка всё та же. Помогите разобраться, что к чему, пожалуйста.

[image: Manager Server Configuration Wizard]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `Database server` ip адресом указать.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но что-то не помогает. Или я не тот адрес использую? Сайт 2ip.ru показывает мой адрес: 212.42.51.131.Я его ввожу в поле Database Server, но это не решает проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Смогли победить данную проблему путем:

1. SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > enable the TCP/IP protocol, также в свойствах протокола во вкладке IP Address дописываем 1433 в TCP Port. Перезагружаем SQL Server service.
2. Добавление в firewall правила(указываем свой IP) :
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SQL Srv_Open static 1433" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=1433 enable=yes profile=ANY remoteip=192.168.1.1 interfacetype=lan
3. В Manadgement Server Configuration Wizard: Database server(указываем IP), SQL server port 1433, Server user name(пользователь через .\ )